# Adding an if-else statement within a label

Tags: java, forms, swing, jlabel

How would I write lines of code for an if-else statement within a label on a form? The user inputs a number and depending on the number, a different statement appears on the form. Do I insert a jLabel, edit text so nothing is inside, and how do I initialize/declare it? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You add the label to the form when you create the form and add all the other components to the form.

Make sure you use a proper layout manager so that when you set the text of the label, the components in the form don't change position.

Then when you want to change the text you do something like:

```
if (someCondition)
    label.setText("someText");
else
    label.setText("someOtherText");
```

This approach is better than adding/removing components from the form.